RangeError in AnimatedList When Removing last Item
I'm building a Flutter app where I use an AnimatedList to manage a dynamic list of rows. Each row contains two TextField widgets, and the user can fill out these fields and then remove the row by pressing a "Save" button. The removal works fine unless i remove the last row at any time I encounter a Error.
class DynamicFormScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DynamicFormScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.onSubmit,
    required this.rowCount,
    required this.workout,
    required this.onNextTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Future<bool> Function(List<Map<String, dynamic>>) onSubmit;
  final VoidCallback onNextTap;
  final int rowCount;
  final Workout workout;

  @override
  State<DynamicFormScreen> createState() => _DynamicFormScreenState();
}

class _DynamicFormScreenState extends State<DynamicFormScreen> {
  // List of TextEditingControllers for each row
  late List<TextEditingController> _firstFieldControllers;
  late List<TextEditingController> _secondFieldControllers;

  // Key for managing the list
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Initialize the controllers for each TextField
    _firstFieldControllers = List.generate(
      widget.rowCount,
      (index) => TextEditingController(),
    );
    _secondFieldControllers = List.generate(
      widget.rowCount,
      (index) => TextEditingController(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose all controllers
    for (var controller in _firstFieldControllers) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
    for (var controller in _secondFieldControllers) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _removeFilledRows() {
    List<int> indicesToRemove = [];
    for (int i = _firstFieldControllers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (_firstFieldControllers[i].text.isNotEmpty &&
          _secondFieldControllers[i].text.isNotEmpty) {
        indicesToRemove.add(i);
      }
    }

    print('Indices to remove: $indicesToRemove'); // Debug statement

    for (int index in indicesToRemove.reversed) {
      print('Removing index: $index'); // Debug statement
      _listKey.currentState?.removeItem(
        index,
        (context, animation) => _buildRemovedItem(context, index, animation),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      );

      // Remove from the controllers list
      _firstFieldControllers.removeAt(index);
      _secondFieldControllers.removeAt(index);
    }

    print(
        'Controllers after removal: $_firstFieldControllers'); // Debug statement
  }

  Widget _buildRemovedItem(
      BuildContext context, int index, Animation<double> animation) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: SizeTransition(
        sizeFactor: animation,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: StatRowTextfields(
            firstFieldControllers: _firstFieldControllers,
            secondFieldControllers: _secondFieldControllers,
            firstIndex: index,
            secondIndex: index,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: AnimatedList(
                key: _listKey,
                initialItemCount: _firstFieldControllers.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                  return FadeTransition(
                    opacity: animation,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: StatRowTextfields(
                        firstFieldControllers: _firstFieldControllers,
                        secondFieldControllers: _secondFieldControllers,
                        firstIndex: index,
                        secondIndex: index,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: CustomButton(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        borderColor: Colors.green,
                        title: 'Save stat',
                        onPressed: () {
                          List<Map<String, dynamic>> inputData = [];
                          for (int i = 0;
                              i < _firstFieldControllers.length;
                              i++) {
                            inputData.add({
                              'reps': _firstFieldControllers[i].text,
                              'weight': _secondFieldControllers[i].text,
                            });
                          }

                          _removeFilledRows();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: CustomButton(
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        borderColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                        onPressed: () {
                          widget.onNextTap();
                        },
                        title: 'Next exercise',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StatRowTextfields extends StatelessWidget {
  const StatRowTextfields({
    super.key,
    required this.firstFieldControllers,
    required this.secondFieldControllers,
    required this.firstIndex,
    required this.secondIndex,
  });
  final List<TextEditingController> firstFieldControllers;
  final List<TextEditingController> secondFieldControllers;
  final int firstIndex;
  final int secondIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          height: 50,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.check_circle,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 40,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 110,
          height: 50,
          child: TextField(
            controller: firstFieldControllers[firstIndex],
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
            ],
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Enter your text',
              labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow, width: 2.0),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 110,
          height: 50,
          child: TextField(
            controller: secondFieldControllers[secondIndex],
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
            ],
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Enter your text',
              labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow, width: 2.0),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Issue:
When I remove the last row I get the following error:

for example i had 4 rows and removed the last saved data in the last row only and pressed save then the row is removed and i get this error 
***
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown building StatRowTextfields(dirty):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 3

The relevant error-causing widget was:
    StatRowTextfields StatRowTextfields:***


